# How can I get the only one next element after a class with JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, class, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to display a list inside a list when users click on the specific icon.
Here is my code.

HTML :

```
<li class="filename"><img src="expand.png" /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<ul class="datalog">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>
<li class="filename">
<img src="expand.png" /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<ul class="datalog">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery :

```
$('.filename img').click(function () {
    $('.filename').next(".datalog").show();
});
```

And here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnxdf/)

I also tried functions like closest or children, probably bad implemented, without success.

In my example there's only two mains lists but in the application the number of lists is variable (so I can't really use an index).

How can I only display the list related to the click ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `this` reference

```
$('.filename img').click(function () {
   $(this).parent().next(".datalog").show();
});
```

**explanation**

```
$(this)-->current clicked element , which is img
parent()--> go to parent which is `li`
.next(".datalog") --> go to the next element whose class is `.datalog`, that is `ul` 
.show()  -->show
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnxdf/1/)

Comment: `$(this)` seems to not working. And if I try to use `$('.filename')` again I've got the same result (btw I realize it's logical since it defines all the class...).

Comment: welcome.. happy coding...glad it helped..:).. just have a look to `toggle()` too.. i think you might need it.. :)

Comment: Oh yes, probably usefull ! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$('.filename img').click(function () {
    $(this)                   // Get the current img being clicked
         .closest('li')       // Go to the closest parent `li` to the img
         .next('.datalog')    // Go to the next sibling of the `li`
         .show();             // Show the `ul` with the class `.datalog`
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnxdf/8/)

You can also try this:

```
$('.filename img').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').next('.datalog').show().siblings('.datalog').hide();
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnxdf/10/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.filename img').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').next(".datalog").show();
});
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/Lnxdf/2/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnxdf/9/

```
$('.filename img').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next('ul.datalog').show();
});
```

Altho i dont really like structure like this

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
$('.filename img').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next().show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnxdf/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this For full process

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.filename img').click(function () {
        if( $(this).closest('li').next('.datalog').is(':hidden')) {
        $(this)                   // Get the current img being clicked
             .closest('li')       // Go to the closest parent `li` to the img
             .next('.datalog')    // Go to the next sibling of the `li`
             .show();             // Show the `ul` with the class `.datalog`
        } else {
               $(this)                   // Get the current img being clicked
             .closest('li')       // Go to the closest parent `li` to the img
             .next('.datalog')    // Go to the next sibling of the `li`
             .hide();             // Show the `ul` with the class `.datalog`
        }
    });
});
```